# Update large dataframe with new entry according to the columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-entry

I have a large dataframe (50+ columns).
I get each row in different order of columns and I need to add a new row to the dataframe but this new row should update the right columns.

For example, I have a `df`:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9  col10 .........
1    a    Don  Lu   854  W    eee  1    1234  yes 
4    s34  Dino Ken  44   S    aaa  1    3432  no
5    1ee  Pupu Dar  2215 R    bbb  -4   12121 yes
```

I get a new entry:

```
col6 col2 col5 col4 col3 col1 col7 col10 col9  col8 .........
R    re3  666  Rino Pino 33   ddd  no    55874 6
```

I thought about `dplyr` arrange function to `arrange` by names and update, 
I can also use `$` to update each one, please advise what is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumming your new entry is a `data.frame()` and called `df1`, I would use `rbindlist()` from the `data.table` package.

```
merged <- list(df, df1)
rbindlist(merged, fill = TRUE)
```

will do the job very quickly. In fact, you can put as many entries you want in the `list`

```
merged <- list(df1, df2, ...... , df99999, df100000)
rbindlist(merged, fill = TRUE)
```

does the job pretty quickly.

Note that any entries in `df1` that are not in `df` and vise-versa will be made `NA` accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just use `merge()` and set the argument `all` as `TRUE`. Try

```
df <- read.table(text = "col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9  col10
                 1    a    Don  Lu   854  W    eee  1    1234  yes 
                 4    s34  Dino Ken  44   S    aaa  1    3432  no
                 5    1ee  Pupu Dar  2215 R    bbb  -4   12121 yes", header=TRUE)
new.entry <- read.table(text = "col6 col2 col5 col4 col3 col1 col7 col10 col9  col8
                                R    re3  666  Rino Pino 33   ddd  no    55874 6", header = TRUE)

merge(df, new.entry, all = TRUE)
#  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8  col9 col10
#    1    a  Don   Lu  854    W  eee    1  1234   yes
#    4  s34 Dino  Ken   44    S  aaa    1  3432    no
#    5  1ee Pupu  Dar 2215    R  bbb   -4 12121   yes
#   33  re3 Pino Rino  666    R  ddd    6 55874    no
```

Comment: I have tried, it doesn't work, can you please post an example?

Comment: While this is the most sensible answer, in terms of efficiency it may not be optimal.

Comment: Do you have any other solution?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example. You are right @InfiniteFlashChess, if there is more than one new entry this is not efficient

Answer (score 1):

bind_rows() from dplyr should also work.

```
data <- data.frame(x = rep("ABC", 3), y = 1, z = 0)
data1 <- data.frame(y = 2, x = rep("XX", 4))
datax <- bind_rows(data, data1)
```